# Python Selenium Vanguard: NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element with Selenium and Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

I am trying to download history data and click on link to historical data. However even though the Xcode is correct I get this error:

```
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element.
```

Code trials:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/Documents/Coding/chromedriver')
url = "https://www.vanguardinvestor.co.uk/investments/vanguard-lifestrategy-100-equity-fund-accumulation-shares/price-performance?intcmpgn=blendedlifestrategy_lifestrategy100equityfund_fund_link"
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='prices-and-performance-tab']/div/div[4]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/table/tfoot/tr/td/a")
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(elem).click(elem).perform()
```

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element wait for the page to load and element to be clickable and then click.Try entire snippet.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/Documents/Coding/chromedriver')
url = "https://www.vanguardinvestor.co.uk/investments/vanguard-lifestrategy-100-equity-fund-accumulation-shares/price-performance?intcmpgn=blendedlifestrategy_lifestrategy100equityfund_fund_link"
driver.get(url)
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()[contains(.,'Price & Performance')]]")))
element.click
```

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element with text as **Search for more historical prices** you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
  options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path = r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe' ) 
  driver.get("https://www.vanguardinvestor.co.uk/investments/vanguard-lifestrategy-100-equity-fund-accumulation-shares/price-performance?intcmpgn=blendedlifestrategy_lifestrategy100equityfund_fund_link")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='bannerButton']"))).click()
  more_historical_prices = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "Search for more historical prices")))
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", more_historical_prices)
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Search for more historical prices")))
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: more_historical_prices]

Comment: This does not work for me, my objective is to open the link so that I can pass keys to the dates so that I can pass the table data to beautiful soup. The suggested code seems to only move the window down and the table does not open. Using inspect I have noticed that the link "Search for more historical prices" is part of a class "vuiNoBotBorder" could this be an issue?